# SQL Server Transactional replication of large number of databases on a server (hundreds) - Best Practices

Tags: sql-server, replication, transactional

We are getting ready to setup SQL Server Transactional replication.  We will have hundreds of databases on each server being replicated to an alternative location (for reporting purposes).  Are there any best practices, gotchas, things to look out for, etc. when having such large number of databases on a publisher?  We do plan to have a dedicated "distributor" box and have separate distribution database for each of the publishing servers.  We expect to have under 10 publishers, but total number of databases among them might approach a few thousand.

Thank you in advance for any pointers!

Comment: The is probably much better asked on dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

as suggested ask to dba.stackexchange.com it's better

From my experience, first of all (cause i had problem) try to know the kb/mb which will be transferred by second and following that check your connection between distributor and subscriber.

Then calculate very much the time it should cost for your publishers' server the time it will use to transfert it to the distributor.

And finaly identify very well which tables you want to replicate, try to forget nothing, it's a relational database so try to keep it relational :)

Thing about security too, if you are on different location you are probably not on same domain, the easiest way i found was to change the host's file from windows to use a logical name and not an IP (required)

After that, your problem will start.... for me replication with different locations was a lots of problem (living in europe and working for companies with bad vpn connection speed).

Good luck :)